# Using preloaded modules in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm little bit unsure about a simple scenario of preloading nodejs modules and using the preloaded instance in my main file.

Let's say I have a preload.js file:

```js
// preload.js
let appInsights = require('applicationinsights')
appInsights.setup('your-instrumentation-key').start()
```

Now I run my application like this:
`node --require preload.js server.js`

I would like to use the instance of preloaded appInsights in my server.js, so I can call some functions it offers, for example:

```js
// server.js
appInsights.defaultClient.trackException(...)
```

But how can I correctly achieve that? I found 2 ways that seems to be working, however, I don't know what's the difference:

1. Add `module.exports = appInsights` to **preload.js** and `let appInsights = require('./preload')` to **server.js**
2. Keep preload.js as it as and add `let appInsights = require('applicationinsights')` to **server.js** (it was using the instance that was initialized in preload.js)

The thing is, in this very simple scenario, both seems to be working the same. When I introduce next.js as my "server" and try preloading my module, it gets different. If I put a simple console.log into my preload.js to see when it runs, the first method seems to output the console.log everytime I `require('preload')`. The second method outputs only when it runs the first time. Nevertheless, both methods seems to work, but I have no idea what happens behind the scenes.

Thanks